Enabling Wayland support for Beekeeper Studio Flatpak
As per documentation Wayland support can be enabled by adding flags to Beekeeper's config file:
https://docs.beekeeperstudio.io/installation/linux/#enabling-wayland-support
However I fail to identify the correct location of the config for Beekeeper's Flatpak version. Does anybody know where the flags should be defined?

There is a more generic question around enabling Wayland support for Electron based apps running as flatpaks (like beekeeper) here That answers your question
